# Symfony 5 - Can I use voter with another user than the current logged one?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security

Usually I use a voter on the user who is connected (me) to see if I can do an action or not.

```php
if ($this->isGranted('TRAVEL', $city)) {
    $this->goToCity($this->getUser(), $city);
}
```

But this time I would like to use my voter on a user that I will search in the database, to check if this user can or can't do this same action.

```php
$another_user = $doctrineStuff->getRepo(Foo:bar)->getUser(123);
if ($this->isGranted('TRAVEL',$city, $another_user)) {
    $this->goToCity($another_user, $city);
}
```

Is this possible?

How to go about it, I can't find anything about this problem. Maybe except simulating a home-made voter that doesn't check a user from his token but from his instance.

Comment: I don't have an example handy but if you look at AuthorizationChecker::isGranted you will see that all it does is to get the token and then call AccessDecisionManager::decide($token,$attribute,$subject);  I remember doing this a few versions ago and it worked fine.

Comment: it use a token, not a entity user. I dont have a token for them. I made a trick that allows to recover the method of verification inside the voter but it's a pity that we can't do it natively I think

Comment: It's trivial to create a token from a user. new UsernamePasswordToken($user,'main',$user->getRoles()); Should be all you really need.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to create your own security token for the user and then use the AccessDecisionManager::decide method instead of the AuthorizationChecker::isGranted method.

```
class SomeController {
    public function someAction(
        AccessDecisionManagerInterface $adm,
        EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $user = $em->find(User::class,123);
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user,'firewall',$user->getRoles());
        if ($adm->decide($token,['TRAVEL'],$city) {
            whatever;
```

Don't worry about the firewall name.  It won't be used by the voter system unless you have a very unusual voter.  It's used in this example because the TokenInterface is surprisingly complex (13 methods!) so it easiest to use an existing implementation.  You could refine things a bit by making your own token class:

```
class UserToken extends AbstractToken {
    public function __construct(User $user) {
        parent::__construct($user->getRoles());
        $this->setUser($user);
```

It's also worth noting that the suggestion to directly use the access decision manager comes from the isGranted code:

```
    # AuthorizationChecker
    final public function isGranted(mixed $attribute, mixed $subject = null): bool
    {
        $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

        if (!$token || !$token->getUser()) {
            $token = new NullToken();
        }

        return $this->accessDecisionManager->decide($token, [$attribute], $subject);
    }
}
```

As time goes by you might want to keep an eye on any tweaks here.  Tweaking the Security component seems to be a bit of a hobby for some of the core Symfony developers.  But I don't expect any breaking changes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Cerad is working if the use case is very simple. For my case, it wasn't working as my Voter had internal calls to the `Security::isGranted()` method. So the token was passed to the Voter but as soon as I reached a `isGranted()` call, it was always returning `false` because it used a `NullToken` instead of my `UsernamePasswordToken`.

To fix this issue, I had to update the TokenStorage to be sure it would be used everywhere. My use case is simple : I queried a few users and must process only those who are 'granted' the access to another entity and discard the others :

```php
// Don't forget to include those classes
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;



// First, I make sure to keep the current token somewhere, just in case
$originalToken = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();

foreach ($alert->getUsers() as $user) {
    // Create a token to use the Voter system
    // If user is not granted, then it's excluded from the process
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken(new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'main', $user->getRoles()));

    // Now I can simply call the AuthorizationChecker instead of the AccessDecisionManager
    if (!$this->authorizationChecker->isGranted(OperationVoter::VIEW, $data)) {
        continue;
    }

    // Keep going and process user
    // ...
}

// At the end, I restore the TokenStorage to it's original state to prevent
// unwanted side-effects to another part of my source code
// I wouldn't want another Voter somewhere to use the wrong User
$this->tokenStorage->setToken($originalToken);
```