# Checking that user has role according to roles hierarchy for not logged user

Tags: symfony

I faced with an issue of checking users permissions.

I know about `AuthorizationChecker` and other stuff for checking permissions for logged users, but I need to go through all the users and do some stuff to users that have specific permission(s) according to the roles hierarchy.

So what can help me replace `isGranted()` method for checking logged user that have token? Do I just need to make my own service to do this? I definitely won't even try to fetch that tokens for all users

Comment: You may be interested in symfony voters https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: Oddly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897603/symfony-5-can-i-use-voter-with-another-user-than-the-current-logged-one/70915768#70915768).  Though I don't understand the thing about not wanting to fetch tokens.  Tokens are not fetched they are created and the entire authorization system is based on tokens.

Comment: @Cerad, by fetch I meant every possible way to get this token to see what user is granted to do: create is included. That’s not a point. I think it’s an overkill to create your own security token to do such simple task. But thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a voter, another implementation of security token just I made a helper class that uses injected `RoleHierarchy` instance from to check is this role exists in given user's roles collection.

**It’s definitely not the right way to do this, but I made it as much simple as I could:**

```
public function isGranted(User $user, string ...$permissions): bool
{
    $reachableRoles = $this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoleNames($user->getRoles());

    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        if (\in_array($permission, $reachableRoles, true)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```